# parsing the date with python 2.7 and regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am converting a text into a JSON file and it works fine but not for all of them.... some of the text formats contain an extra line before Date. For this reason, I would like some code that will skip any information starting with "(" before date. Here is my code: [image]

```
import os
import json
import re

with open(_file, 'r') as _f:
        article = {}
        f = nonblank_lines(_f)
        for line in f:
            if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):
                next(f)
                article['date'] = next(f).strip()
```

Comment: Do you mean skip over lines that have `(` before the line with the date?

Comment: exactly that Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if '(' in line:`

```
if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):
    next(f)
    line = next(f)
    if '(' in line:
        line = next(f)
    article['date'] = line.strip()
```

Comment: I get "IndentationError: unexpected indent" in the first "line = next(f)" any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're consistent in your use of tabs vs spaces in your indenting.

Comment: perfect, will do. Thanks